# Days passing application Android

Tags: android

Can someone tell me a simple method to track if a day has passed since the opening of an Activity? Also, do something if has passed and something if not. Thank you!

This is my code. I get this class exceptions as if I want to save an int into a long and don't know where.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();       
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    long aux_time = prefs.getLong("AUX", -1);
    int aux_day= prefs.getInt("DAY", -1);

    if(System.currentTimeMillis()!=aux_time&&calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)!=aux_day)
    {  
        ... // Open "Not allowed Activity"
    }

    else            
    {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("AUX", System.currentTimeMillis());
    editor.putInt("DAY", calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    editor.commit();
    ... //  Open Activity            

}
```

Any opinions? 
 EDIT: Ahh, about that Int class exception, forgot to clean the editor. Also, the code still doesn't work well.

Comment: Do you mean something like "x days since you last launched me." ?

Comment: In the end I want to make an application that lets the user to do something with a restriction of 1 opening per day. So, I need a code that will see if the Activity(which needs to be open only once a day) can be opened in this respective time or not. If yes, proceed, if not, another activity comes in.

Comment: An "x hours since you launched me" activity will be the negative condition in my once per day open Activity. I mean, if the user can't see it, it will be redirected to that "x hours" activity. I just need a code to check if the user can open the activity or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do this...you were close but some of the logic is wrong.

```
{ 
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

    long savedDate = prefs.getLong(PreferenceKeys.SAVED_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    if ((savedDate + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {

         prefsEditor.putLong(Constants.PREF_SERVER_BATCH_TIME, currentTime);

        // 24 hours has passed...your code here.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store and retrieve the `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If you need to know day rather than 24 hours you'll just also need to use [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do now. I think that I will need an If with two conditions (if currentTime<savedTime and if currentday!=savedday)

Comment: Ahh, still couldn't find out how to do it. Can someone help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you open that activity (in oncreate() ) add value to sharedpreferences with info about Current Day/Date or Time(if want to trace 24hrs instead of day) using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Before saving that check that if this time(this day)  has not been saved yet and proceed accordingly..

Comment: Edited up there. Please have a look.